# Issue while trying to submit the Feed for POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA

Tags: python, c#, php, xml, amazon-selling-partner-api

Can you please suggest if there are errors in the xml posted below?

**Error Details**

We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed

**Official link to sample xsd**: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/xsd/release_4_1/OrderFulfillment.xsd

**XML for POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='amzn-envelope.xsd'>
    <Header>
        <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
        <MerchantIdentifier>Sample</MerchantIdentifier>
    </Header>
    <MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
    <Message>
        <MessageID>1</MessageID>
        <OrderFulfillment>
            <AmazonOrderID>113-sampl-sample</AmazonOrderID>
            <FulfillmentData>
                <CarrierCode>UPS</CarrierCode>
                <CarrierName>UPS</CarrierName>
                <ShippingMethod>UPC Ground</ShippingMethod>
                <ShipperTrackingNumber>Sample ID</ShipperTrackingNumber>
            </FulfillmentData>
            <Item>
                <AmazonOrderItemCode>Sample ASIN</AmazonOrderItemCode>
                <MerchantOrderItemID>Sample merchant order id</MerchantOrderItemID>
                <Quantity>1</Quantity>
            </Item>
        </OrderFulfillment>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```