# Go Code is not printing posted json value from jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, go, goland

**Issue details**

Go Code is not printing posted json value from jquery ajax

**Go Code Main**

```
routing := chi.NewRouter()
routing.Post("/authenticate", AuthenticateRouter)
```

**Go Code**

```
func AuthenticateRouter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    username := r.PostForm.Get("username")
    fmt.Println(r.PostFormValue("username"))  //Not showing posted value
    fmt.Println(r.Form.Get("username"))       //Not showing posted value
    fmt.Println(r.Form.Get("username"))       //Not showing posted value
}
```

**JQuery ajax code**

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "post",
    "url": "authenticate",
    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    "dataType": "json",
    "data": JSON.stringify({
        "username": $(form).find("[name='username']").val(),
        "password": $(form).find("[name='password']").val(),
    }),
    beforeSend: function() {
    },
    success: function(response) {
        debugger;
    },
    error: function(response) {
        debugger;
    },
    complete: function(response) {
        debugger;
    }
});
```

**html**

```
<form class="loginForm form-signin"><br>    
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

Comment: `PostForm` will not parse JSON. It will work with URL encoded data. Either change the AJAX call to use url-encoded values, or in the handler read the request body, umarshal JSON and get the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending JSON data, but `PostForm` works with URL-encoded data. You can do:

```
type authBody struct {
   Username string `json:"username"`
   Password string `json:"password"`
}

func AuthenticateRouter(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
   dec:=json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
   var body authBody
   if err:=dec.Decode(&body); err!=nil {
      // deal with err
   }
   // Work with body.Username and body.Password
}
```

Comment: Did you define the `authBody` struct as show in the code?

Comment: Would you like to put some useful thoughts here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76812734/issue-while-trying-to-submit-the-feed-for-post-order-fulfillment-data